# Как интегрировать нейронную сеть в приложение?

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
def Network(self):
        faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_russian_plate_number.xml')
        video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('Vidos/trek.mp4')  # Выбираем устройство видеозахвата

        while True:
                ret, frame = video_capture.read()

                # Получаем серую картинку
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

                plaques = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
                for i, (x, y, w, h) in enumerate(plaques):
                        roi_color = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                        cv2.putText(frame, str(x) + " " + str(y) + " " + str(w) + " " + str(h), (480, 220),
                                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255))
                        r = 400.0 / roi_color.shape[1]
                        dim = (400, int(roi_color.shape[0] * r))
                        resized = cv2.resize(roi_color, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
                        w_resized = resized.shape[0]
                        h_resized = resized.shape[1]

                        frame[100:100 + w_resized, 100:100 + h_resized] = resized
                cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                        break
```

Нейронная сеть представляет собой выше упомянутую функцию. Как ее вызвать в Pyqt5 для дальнейшего отображения в приложении?

```
        self.Video = QVideoWidget(self.Camera)
        self.Video = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(None, QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.Video.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(Network(self))))
        self.Video.setVideoOutput(self.ui.widget)
        self.Video.play()
```

Код выше - просто запускает нейронную сеть, при этом приложение не отображается.

Comment: Наверное, вы всё же имели в виду "интегрировать"

Comment: Верно подметили)